# Kyoto Cabinet Installation Issue

Tags: java, database, key-value, tokyo-cabinet, kyotocabinet

I have installed [Kyoto Cabinet](http://fallabs.com/kyotocabinet/) by using instruction from [this](http://fallabs.com/kyotocabinet/javadoc/). However, [this](http://fallabs.com/kyotocabinet/javadoc/) says you have to add **kyotocabinet.jar** in your class path to compile a java file. But, I have not find anywhere the **kyotocabinet.jar** file. I try to add kyotocabinet.jar by using their commands. That also not works. Can anybody help me, why this is happening and how to solve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jar file is part of the Binary Package.

You can find the kyotocabinet.jar in this file: http://fallabs.com/kyotocabinet/winpkg/.
Its inside *java/* folder

Comment: No. I am asking about, to run java file I have to give command javac -cp /path/kytocabinet.jar Test.java. What is the path ?

Comment: Try full path to the jar file on the filesystem

Comment: And to install kyoto cabinet what files should I have to install ?

Comment: I only install last .gz of this (http://fallabs.com/kyotocabinet/javapkg/). Is this ok ?

Comment: And issue is, there is no .jar file. I have to do it for Java-Linux.

Comment: The same jar file should work for Linux but you'll need to compile the native code

Comment: I can install (what pkg you provided) for windows also. But, how to install it for windows any link or idea ?

Comment: There is a `doc` folder in the package but that sounds like a separate question